# Async Await returns a promise and not the object

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to get files from the function `getPageFiles`, but only after the two axios post commands are done, on the success of the second axios, return the file object. I am not sure why files are a Promise instead of a list of objects?

```
 async function getPageFiles() {
      return connectionInfo.files.map(
        (file) => {
          return axios
            .post(
              API_ROUTE,
              {
                file_name: file.file_name,
              },
              {
                headers: {
                  "Content-Type": "application/json",
                  authorization,
                },
                params: { presignedUrl: true },
              }
            )
            .then((response: any) => {
              const res = JSON.parse(response);
              // PUT request: upload file to S3
              return axios
                .put(res.uploadURL, file.binary)
                .then((s3Response: TResponseError | any) => {
                    return {
                      file_type: "csv",
                      s3_path: `s3://${process.env.TEST}/${file.file_name}`,
                      table_name: file.table_name.toUpperCase(),
                    }
                  }

                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
                  console.error(`Error putting file to s3 upload URL: ${error}`);
                });
            });
        }
      );
    };


    let files = await getPageFiles();
```

Comment: I believe you should be using [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)...

Comment: I am using async/await and I would like to continue with it, do you have a suggestion on how to do it using existing code? @vera.

Comment: Wrap your `map` call in `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you aren't actually waiting for the promises *inside* the array to resolve. You're currently doing something like this:

```js
(async () => {

const result = await Promise.resolve([
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 1)),
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 2)),
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 3)),
]);

// trying to use the resulting array of numbers
console.log(result.map((x) => x * 2));

})();
```

See how `NaN` is logged instead of `2`, `4`, `6`? That's because in this example, `x` is still a promise that hasn't been resolved, so you can't use it like a number. You probably meant to use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) which return a new promise that resolves when all the promises in the array resolve:

```js
(async () => {

const result = await Promise.all([
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 1)),
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 2)),
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 500, 3)),
]);

// trying to use the resulting array of numbers
console.log(result.map((x) => x * 2));

})();
```

So how would it look like in your code? Well, just wrap your map:

```
async function getPageFiles() {
    return Promise.all(connectionInfo.files.map((files) => {
        // ...
    }));
}
```